# LogIn Form Show message when Email and Password doesnt match or Email doesnt exist

Tags: php, authentication, user-input, verify

I have a login form that shows a message when password input is wrong but email isnt. But it doesnt show anything when email or both arent right. I wanted it to show the message ("Password and email doesnt match") in both of those cases missing. Id really apreciate any help.

```
  <div id="container">
            <div>
                <h1>Log In</h1>
                <form method="POST" action="logIn.php">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input name= "txtEmail"/>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="txtPass"/>
                    <input type= "submit" name= "submit" value="Log In"/>
                </form>
            </div>  
        </div>

<?php

    require ('connection.php');

            if (isset($_POST["txtEmail"]))
            {
            $email= $_POST["txtEmail"];//NO RECONOCE LOS TEXT FIELDS!!
            }
            else
            {$email= "";
            echo "Email empty";}

            if (!empty($_POST['txtPass']))
            {
            $pass= $_POST['txtPass'];
            }
            else
            {$pass= "";
            echo "Password empty.";}

            // Enviar consulta
              $instruction = "SELECT Password, Email FROM customer WHERE Email = '". $email . "'";
              $query = mysql_query ($instruction, $connection)
                 or die ("Fallo en la consulta");       
           // Mostrar resultados de la consulta
              $nrows = mysql_num_rows ($query);
              if ($nrows > 0)
              {
                    $result = mysql_fetch_array ($query);
                    if (isset($result['Password']))
                    {
                    $clave = $result['Password'];
                    //echo "Isset password works.";
                    }
                    else {$result= "";}
                    Email doesnt exist, or ;}


                    if ($clave == $pass){
                        header('Location: welcomeLogIn.php');
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "Password or Email doesnt match.";
                    }
              }
    mysql_close($connection);
    ?>
```

Comment: wrong in so many ways, un-hashed password, mysql_*, un-sanatised inputs

Comment: You also should not provide spammers with a away to get valid emails from your site. That is why it is always "Username/password don't match." Do not get potential attackers more informaiton.

Comment: I know for a fact it aint secure enough. Im just developing the basic functionality, so then Ill add up the security measures. I know very well you should show a message like "Email and password doesnt match", but at the moment I was frustrated trying the code to show a message after a bad login.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for providing your code for us to review. Based on the code I can see that you are just starting to learn PHP. I have updated your code with a very simple way to do what you are asking. Basically if the e-mail or password is empty then it sets the $empty_value variable to 1. Then at the end of the script it checks to see if the $empty_value variable is equal to 1. If it is the message you wanted will be printed. Please note that there are many security issues regarding your code and I suggest reading all of the information in the following guide: http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/.

```
<?php

    require ('connection.php');
$empty_value = 0;

            if (isset($_POST["txtEmail"]))
            {
            $email= $_POST["txtEmail"];//NO RECONOCE LOS TEXT FIELDS!!
            }
            else
            {$email= "";
            $empty_value = 1;}

            if (!empty($_POST['txtPass']))
            {
            $pass= $_POST['txtPass'];
            }
            else
            {$pass= "";
            $empty_value = 1;}

            // Enviar consulta
              $instruction = "SELECT Password, Email FROM customer WHERE Email = '". $email . "'";
              $query = mysql_query ($instruction, $connection)
                 or die ("Fallo en la consulta");       
           // Mostrar resultados de la consulta
              $nrows = mysql_num_rows ($query);
              if ($nrows > 0)
              {
                    $result = mysql_fetch_array ($query);
                    if (isset($result['Password']))
                    {
                    $clave = $result['Password'];
                    //echo "Isset password works.";
                    }
                    else {$result= "";}
                    Email doesnt exist, or ;}


                    if ($clave == $pass){
                        header('Location: welcomeLogIn.php');
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "Password or Email doesnt match.";
                    }
              }
    mysql_close($connection);
    ?>

<?php
if ($empty_value == 1) {
echo "Password or Email doesn't match.";
}
?>

  <div id="container">
            <div>
                <h1>Log In</h1>
                <form method="POST" action="logIn.php">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input name= "txtEmail"/>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="txtPass"/>
                    <input type= "submit" name= "submit" value="Log In"/>
                </form>
            </div>  
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But still doesnt work. When I type a random email and a random password no message is shown.

Comment: @Mijail, I just made a couple changes to the code, please try it now.

Answer (score 0):

If there is not matching email, then you will get no results so you could simple add:

```
if ($nrows > 0)
{
   //You current code to check if the password is correct                 
}
else{
  echo "No matching email found";
}
```

Comment: Molte grazie. Your answer does work. Though I had to cut the php code to another file called logIn3.php and change the action (form) redirecting to that file, because if not "No matching email found" showed when the page first loaded. Im just saying in case someone is browsing hoping for an answer and want the whole explanation.